# Magento Autoload.php(93) Error no such file or directory in admin > system > configuration

Tags: php, magento

I went through a very painful process for around 10 hours last night upgrading a magento store from 1.4.1 to 1.9 which is all done however there is 1 final issue which i am struggling with and wondering if anyone knows as searching google has not really come up with anything.

When i login to admin and goto system > configuration i get the following:

```
Warning: include(Mage/Awall/Helper/Data.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/seedpant/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

#0 /home/seedpant/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(Mage/Aw...', '/home/seedpant/...', 93, Array)
#1 /home/seedpant/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_Awall_Help...')
#3 /home/seedpant/public_html/dev/app/Mage.php(547): spl_autoload_call('Mage_Awall_Help...')
#4 /home/seedpant/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Tabs.php(117): Mage::helper('awall')
#5 /home/seedpant/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(104): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Tabs->initTabs()
#6 /home/seedpant/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#7 /home/seedpant/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#8 /home/seedpant/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /home/seedpant/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /home/seedpant/public_html/dev/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /home/seedpant/public_html/dev/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

Now i cannot find anything really online about AWall and cannot see the full error paths to locate where its coming from as ill just disable it other wise but does anyone know? or maybe how i can locate and remove this or if you know what it is download and get it installed so its found and loads correctly

Thanks in advance
James

Comment: i have noticed something that it is calling Mage/AWall/Helper and looking on FTP it should  be Mage/AW/All/Helper - anyone know where these paths are set so i can change it as must be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this file `Mage/Awall/Helper/Data.php` exists on the `app/code/local` folder, probably your previous magento version had this file inside the `app/code/core` and was removed on update.

If the file exist, check the if class in the file is correct

Comment: It did not, however i did notice some files and folders were missing for some reason... must of been from the upgrading but got it sorted now.